# Fetching instagram api not working on wordpress

Tags: php, api, json

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/userid/media/recent/?access_token=accesstoken');
$a_json = json_decode($json, true);
foreach( $a_json['data'] as $key => $value) {
  $a_images[$value['id']]['link'] = $value['link'];
  $a_images[$value['id']]['url'] = $value['images']['standard_resolution']['url'];
  $a_images[$value['id']]['caption'] = $value['caption']['text'];
}


echo '<ul>';
$i = 0;
 foreach($a_images as $image)
 {
  if ($i < 3) {
    echo '<li class="large-4 columns">
        <div class="front">
            <a href="'.$image['link'].'" target="_blank">
                <img src="'.$image['url'].'"/>
            </a>
        </div>

        <div class="back">
            <p>'.$image['caption'].'</p>
        </div>
    </li>';
    $i++;
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
```

I dont know why but this code seems to be not running on my wordpress. What issues should i be looking at? But when i compile this on some online compiler it works.

Got these errors.

```
PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/*******/media/recent/?access_token=*****count=50): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error\r\n in /var/www/vhosts/******* on line 151

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/*********on line 153

PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /var/www/vhosts/*****on line 162
```

Comment: I think the problem is with the URL. Try sending a request with the `curl` command and check if it is the right URL. Also use `wp_remote_get()` as it is the WordPress way of doing GET requests.

Comment: `<?php
$json = wp_remote_get('https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/id/media/recent/?access_token=access');
$a_json = json_decode($json, true);`  I tried this and seems to be not working as well is this what you mean?

Comment: Print the `$json` variable and see what is contains - `print_r( $json );`. It should have the API response at `$json['body']`

Comment: I got an error
`WP_Error Object ( [errors] => Array ( [http_request_failed] => Array ( [0] => Operation timed out after 5000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received ) ) [error_data] => Array ( ) )`

Comment: I think your host does not allow remote connections from the server. Try the same code locally on MAMP/WAMP/LAMP.

Comment: It worked do you know where can i turn this on? Or how?

Comment: Where did it work? Did you try locally or did it work on the web host?

Comment: on XAMPP local host. What settings should i look next to make this work on a plesk server?

Comment: Is it your own server (VPS or dedicated)? If it is a shared hosting server you have to ask the web hosting provider to __allow outbound connections via port 443__. On a VPS/dedicated server edit the __php.ini__ file, find `allow_url_fopen` and set it to `1`